# Extending AngularJS filter or building a custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I like how AngularJS filter works and would just like to add a function to the existing one to allow arrays to be used to see if a value is in the array.

If I have the following data:

```
Queue = [
    {'Name':'John','Tier':'Gold','Status':'VIP'},
    {'Name':'Anna','Tier':'Silver','Status':'Normal'},
    {'Name':'Luke','Tier':'Gold','Status':'Normal'},
    {'Name':'Mary','Tier':'Bronze','Status':'Normal'},
    {'Name':'Jess','Tier':'Bronze','Status':'VIP'},
];
Priority = ['Gold','Silver'];
```

I want to list the names of all my Priority members that are also VIPs.

```
<div ng-repeat="people in Queue | filter: {Tier:Priority} | filter: {Status:'VIP'}">{{ people.Name }}</div>
```

I would like to add the ability for filter to check if Tier equals one of the items in the Priority array.

I have looked at building a custom filter with AngularJS but I don't know how to make that customer filter work the same as the existing filter i.e. being able to handle objects, strings or functions like the existing one does.

I'm not so much after the code for checking if an item exists in an array, I'm after the code for creating the filter in the same way where I can then add code to detect if the value given is a string or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use regular expression in this case to check by custom filter.

In .html:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
     <tr ng-repeat="item in Queue | regex:'Tier':Priority | filter:{Status :'VIP'}">
  </body>
```

And custom filter:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('regex', function() {
  return function(input, field, priList) {
     var result = [];
     var priListExp = priList.join("|");
     var patt = new RegExp(priListExp, "i"); // without , "i" if you want to use case insensitive
      input.forEach( function(pri){
         if(patt.test(pri[field])) {
           result.push(pri);
         }
     });

  return result;
  }
});
```

demo : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BaIFoSikYyQ1mRfTju40)

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea, its not a working code. If you pass the arguments in filter, u can write it down something like this :

```
module.filter('filterName', function() {
return function(input, tier, status) {
 if (input.Tier == tier)
 {
  //do something
 }
 if (input.Status == status)
 {
  //do something
 }
 return input;
}   
});
```

At html -

```
<div ng-repeat="people in Queue | filterName:'Priority':'VIP'">{{ people.Name }}</div>
```